# How to call Viewmodel via layout handler in Magneto 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

This is my layout file where i need to call Viewmodel so that it can be used by block .

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.review">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Vendor\ModuleName\ViewModel\Test</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: need to which magento version are you working as per tag you are looking solution for M2.1, please correct me if i wrong. **XSI type object is not available in Magento 2.0 or 2.1**.

Comment: you can follow https://www.yireo.com/blog/2017-08-12-viewmodels-in-magento-2

Comment: @Kanhaiyalal i am working on magento 2.3